# Breaking out of complex loop structure in Java

Tags: java, loops

Im a beginner in Java. I have the following loop structure:

```
loop1:
for(int j=0; j<a.size(); j++){

    if(a.get(j).equals(10)){
        System.out.println(a.get(j));
    } else {
        do {
            System.out.println(a.get(j));
        } while(a.get(j).equals(20)); 
        break loop1;
    }
}
```

This is a basic structure of what im trying to do. So I want to break out of the `for` loop when the `do while` loop in the `else` part is satisfied(the do- while loop executes once irrespective of condition mentioned, I dont want to exit the loop then, but I want to exit the loop when the condition is actually satisfied). How do I do that? I tried breaking as shown in code, but it stops after first iteration through `do-while` loop. Where am I going wrong?

I want to print the values in the `ArrayList a` starting from 10 until 20...and 10 can be anywhere in the list and not the beginning.

```
Eg. ArrayList a contains {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13...20}
I want to print values in the ArrayList from values 10 to 20 (including 10 and 20).
```

There are no duplicate elements in the list. So there is only one 10 and one 20 in the list and it is always in the increasing order.

Comment: Is your condition being met the first time you go into your do while? Because if that's the case, it's working as intended

Comment: @JREN Yes the first time the condition in the `do while` loop is met. But I want to break the loop only after the condition is completely satisfied..not just once

Comment: Could you explain exactly what it is you're trying to achieve?  Im not sure what you see as the condition being "completely satisfied"

Comment: This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Can you tell what you are trying to achieve? This code is perfectly fine, but apparently not what you expect.

Comment: WHat you mean "completely satisfied"? You check if something equals 20, this is either staisfied or not. There is no third possibility.

Comment: Well, your condition is met so you go out of your loop and then it breaks out of the for loop so your code is working as intended.

Comment: @ all: the `do-while` is executed once irresptive of what the condition is. But I want to exit the loop only after the condition is met and not the first time it enters the `do-while` loop

Comment: But this exactly is what happens! Consider a.get(j) is *not* 20, it would loop forever and never break loop1.

Comment: Please tell the expected output

Comment: As it stands, the code would print all leading `10` in a, then, if `20`occurs, it prints that and exits the loop. If something that is not `10`and not `20` occurs, it prints that forever.

Comment: @adi I want to print the values in the ArrayList a starting from 10 until 20...and 10 can be anywhere in the list and not the beginning

Comment: @Ingo  I want to print the values in the ArrayList a starting from 10 until 20...and 10 can be anywhere in the list and not the beginning

Comment: I think it might help if you could provide an example input and output. It's unclear what you mean by "starting from 10 until 20".

Comment: Give an exact output example please

Comment: @adi example added in question

Comment: And if the array was {1, 10, 30, 20, 2, 10, 30}, what would be printed?

Comment: @Oak no matter where 10 and 20 are in the array or if there is/is not any elements between them, I just want to get values between 10 and 20 in the array.

Comment: @Oak There is only one 10 and one 20 in the list...there are no duplicates...if that is what you meant to ask

Comment: "between" is ambiguous here. 30 is between 10 and 20 in that array, and 30 is not between 10 and 20 as natural numbers. Which "between" are you referring to? **What would be printed from that array?** Will it be "10, 20, 10" or "1, 30, 20" or "10, 30, 20, 10, 30" or "10, 20" or...

Comment: @Oak from the array you have suggested...I expect the output to be 10,30,20

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to compare between rounded off long values and long values in ArrayList?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364478/how-to-compare-between-rounded-off-long-values-and-long-values-in-arraylist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int i=0;
boolean found10,found20;
found10=false;
found20=false;
while(i<a.size&&(!found20))
{
    if(a.get(i)==10)
        found10 = true;
    if(found10)
        System.out.println(a.get(i));
    if(a.get(i)==20)
        found20 = true;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: This would print 10 30 20 for array 1 2 3 10 30 20 15

Comment: Sure, boolean flags provide a nice way for controlling looping even when its complicated (atleast for me)

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to do what you want is via a flag:

```
boolean printing = false;
for (int n : a) {
    if (n == 10) printing = true;
    if (printing) System.out.println(n);
    if (n == 20) break;
}
```

If you insist on using a nested loop, your solution was very very close, you only missed a critical `i++` inside the inner loop, and of course its condition was reversed. Also, you are not breaking from an inner loop, you're breaking from an outer loop; so you don't need a label.

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); a++) {
    if (a.get(i).equals(10)) {
        do {
            System.out.println(n);
            i++;
        } while (! a.get(i).equals(20));
        break;
    }
}
```

Also, be wary of corner cases. What happens if 10 appears but 20 doesn't? What happens if 20 appears before 10? What happens if there are multiple 10s or 20s? For example, my 2nd snippet might crash for some of those (because of i++ without checking the array size). Once you know how the corner cases should behave, you should modify those snippets accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are putting some wrong logic there. If `a.get(j).equals(10)` is not `true` then either the `for` loop will break in first iteration of `j` or you will end up in infinite loop as the value of `j` will never change.

Answer (score -1):

According to this comment:

> I want to print the values in the ArrayList a starting from 10 until
>   20...and 10 can be anywhere in the list and not the beginning

interpreted such that the arraylist contains 10 somewhere and possibly 20 somewhere further down the list and all numbers between the first 10 and the first 20 should be printed:

```
j = 0;
while (j < a.size() && a.get(j) != 10) j++;
if (j < a.size()) do {
    print (a.get(j)); j++;
} while (j < a.size() && a.get(j) != 20);
```

Answer (score -1):

According to your statement

`I want to print the values in the ArrayList a starting from 10 until 20...and 10 can be anywhere in the list and not the beginning`

You can use following code:

```
for(int j=0; j<a.size(); j++){
   int number = Integer.parseInt(a.get(j).toString());
   if(number>=10 && number<=20){
     System.out.println(number);
   }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Everyone else has fixed your loop.

To answer the question in the title, the easiest way to break out of a complex loop is to put the complex loop in a method, and use the return statement.

Using your code as an example,

```
public void someMethod(List<Object> a) {
    for (int j = 0; j < a.size(); j++) {
        if (a.get(j).equals(10)) {
            System.out.println(a.get(j));
        } else {
            do {
                System.out.println(a.get(j));
            } while (a.get(j).equals(20));
            return;
        }
    }
}
```