# how to compare between rounded off long values and long values in ArrayList?

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java. I have the following situation:

The `ArrayList` contains `{10234, 20233, 34546, 43546, 59865, 70002, 92435, 200354}`
And the user inputs `20000` and `50000`

And I want to get values from the ArrayList between 20000 and 50000, in this case I expect 20233, 34546, 43546 as answer.

How do I do this?

This is the code I have so far:

```
int t1 = 20233, t2 = 59865;
int i = 0;
boolean foundt1, foundt2;
foundt1 = false;
found20 = false;
while (i < a.size && (!foundt2)) {
    if (a.get(i) == 10) {
        foundt1 = true;
    }
    if (foundt1) {
        System.out.println(a.get(i));
    }
    if (a.get(i) == 20) {
        foundt2 = true;
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Questions must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Tell us what you've tried to do, why it didn't work, and how it should work

Comment: @StinePike I dont know..how to proceed at all :(

Comment: @Raedwald I input the exact values i.e 20233 and 59865 for eg and Im able to get the values

Comment: @user2358330 : create a class and a main function

Comment: @Raedwald I dont know how to work it out when the numbers are rounded off like in my example

Comment: go through the list and check if the element of the list is between the given values

Comment: Some hints to accolmplish your goal

iterate through all element and check if the value is in between the two values

Comment: do some R&D this is too much simple even if you are `beginner`

Comment: @Raedwald I have added the code that I have so far.

Comment: Still lacking some information. Is your list sorted? Does the output need to be sorted? ect. What specific do you expect from your code.

Anyway even as a beginner it should be fairly easy to have one of the bigger search engines tell you how to iterate over a list comparing it with your requirements (element >_(>=)_ 20000 && element <_(<=)_ 50000). If it matches do whatever you want with that element, if not continue iterating until the list is done... Which btw the code of Goatcat already is doing.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Breaking out of complex loop structure in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17342342/876298)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of what you are trying to do.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> numberList = Arrays.asList(10234, 20233, 34546, 43546, 59865, 70002, 92435, 200354);

        for(int nbr : numberList){              //goes through the list
            if( nbr > 20000 && nbr < 50000){
                System.out.println(nbr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Best Regards, Goatcat

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [*Guava library*](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/).

The [*Iterables*](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release02/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html) and [*Range*](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Range.html) classes can solve your task.

The sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<Integer> values = Arrays.asList(10234, 20233, 34546, 43546, 59865, 70002, 92435, 200354);
    Iterable<Integer> filteredValues = Iterables.filter(values, Range.closed(20000, 50000));
    for (Integer val : filteredValues) {
        System.out.println(val);
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
20233
34546
43546
```

---

You cand find more info [here](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/RangesExplained)